# Text from a file formatted as a array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have in a file (.txt) something like this:

```
A[1]=[722680,1,86,121,'Sevilla','Granada CF'....]
A[2]=[807806,29,16516,2007,'Centro Sportivo Paraibano'...]
```

(A string formatted as a array)

I want to load those lines(with jquery) and manipulate it like any other arrays.

EX:

```
if(A[i][16]!="0") G_yellow = "<img src='images/yellow" + A[i][16] +  ".gif' alt='' />";
```

I need a idea of script to do that.

THanks!

Comment: Why not format it as JSON and read it as an object?

Comment: I get these lines from a source and save them as they are.

Comment: Modify the source that is creating this data - this is an inefficient method of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eval to execute the JavaScript in the file:

```
  eval(str);//where str is the file
```

Now you have access to the variables defined in the file, and can manipulate the arrays.

If you need the code to retrieve the file, you can look into using jQuery's get method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get('test.txt', function(data) {
  eval(data);
});
```

Note: Evaluating raw JavaScript on a production server, and not having control over the file is a definite security risk

Comment: Be very careful with `eval`, though - always a BIG security loophole

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee - if you have control over the text file you should be fine, no difference from writing your own javascript right

Comment: True - but why use this method of interaction with the source script in the first place? If this is running on a production server somewhere, that eval function will forever remain a security hole in the middle.

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee - I agree that storing raw js is not ideal.  If this is running on a production server, and there is no control over the file than this is definitely a security risk, I will add this to the answer